# iOS Web-App loads from database in Chrome, but not in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, database, google-chrome, safari

I have a web-app I'm building and want to enable users to bookmark this to homescreen on their iPhone and have it respond like a regular app.
To do this it needs to work in Safari iOS.

I used Chrome Browser when developing this, and it all works well. Pushing the Explore button loads up the content from the database and displays it.

Upon switching to Safari so the homescreen link to fullscreen could happen, the content does not load when pushing the Explore Button.

Please help. I'm unsure as to why it is working fine in Chrome but not in Safari.

The link to visit and see this app for yourself is
[www.arakura.school.nz/mana/](http://www.arakura.school.nz/mana/)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like you trying to develop a PWA. As far as I know the PWA support is not yet on iOS. Only android devices fully support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. I cleared all the cache on my phone and tried again. Ended up loading everything as planned. Thanks